# Template Joomla

Tags: css, joomla, joomla2.5

I'm trying to create my own template in Joomla 2.5, and here is my structure of the template :

I have in the bottom  three boxes

- box 1
- box 2
- box 3

How I can put my articles in these boxes similar to this template  [Template example](http://www.omegatheme.com/joomla/travel-template-ot-tourim.html)?
any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Template of joomla can have only one place for displaying content (for example, 'articles') - `<jdoc:include type="component" />`.
In bottom area you should insert position for modules

```
<div id="box1"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="box1" /></div>
<div id="box2"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="box2" /></div>
<div id="box3"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="box3" /></div>
```

After, for each position, you should assign module with content. http://extensions.joomla.org - this site help you find module for displaying articles.
Also you can adjust bottom area in such way
`<div id="box1"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="box1" /></div>` - in this case you should assign 3 modules on one position or one module which will display 3 articles.